# Prevent Visual Studio from jumping to first error when build fails

Tags: visual-studio

As Visual Studio 2022 builds, you can watch the status in the log, catch build errors. When the build fails the focus is automatically changed to focus on the error window. I find this distracting. I would like to prevent this behavior.

When the build fails I want the active window to retain focus.

Anyway to do that?